# Failed to collect dependencies at com.marklogic-datahub-jar:4.3.1

Tags: maven, dependencies, pom.xml, marklogic-9, sts

Failed to read artifact descriptor for com.marklogic:marklogic-data-hub:jar:4.3.1: Could not transfer artifact com.fasterxml.jackson:jackson-bom:pom:2.9.7 from/to jcenter (http://jcenter.bintray.com)

I am trying to build a project on STS and while doing the Maven build, I am receiving the same error.
Tried to update with forced snapshots and clean install. Had no luck resolving the issue.

Comment: Can you post the relevant portion of your pom.xml (and/or settings.xml). Specifically, looking to see what repositories do you have configured and the options.